# Get rotateY() of element as variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

For an ajax animation on my website I need to check if an element has a full transform to

```
transform: rotateY(-90deg)
```

I found this code on the internet to check an elements css value

```
function getStyle(oElm, strCssRule){
    var strValue = "";
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
        strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
    }
    else if(oElm.currentStyle){
        strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){
            return p1.toUpperCase();
        });
        strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
    }
    return strValue;
}
```

usage:

```
getStyle(document.getElementById('to-transform'), "transform")
```

this will return a matrix3d, which can be different in many browsers like 'internet explorer' and also be different in other versions like IE7 and IE8:

```
matrix3d(0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) safari
matrix3d(0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) chrome
matrix3d(0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1) opera
matrix3d(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)                                                                   firefox
```

is there an easier way to check if an element has a rotateY(-90deg)? So the code can finish the last part of the animation

**Note:** it must be javascript because I haven't included jQuery

Comment: `matrix3d` is the "normalised" format of a transformation - similar to how `red` as a colour is converted to `rgb(255,0,0)`. The only way to get the original string back is to go and read the stylesheet itself, not the computed styles.

Comment: One problem, the rotateY(-90deg) is created by javascript. If I understand you, to get the rotateY() I have to create a function which will transform the matrix3d to rotateY()?